# How to optimize searching and comparing rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two dfs. Base is 100k rows, Snps is 54k rows.

This is structure of dfs:

base:

```
SampleNum SampleIdInt   SecondName
  1         ASA2123313  A2123313
  2         ARR4112234  R4112234
  3         AFG4234122  G4234122
  4         GGF412233   F412233
  5         GTF423512   F423512
  6         POL23523552 L23523552
...
```

And this is `Snps` df:

```
   SampleNum SampleIdInt
      1         ART2114155
      2         KWW4112234
      3         AFG4234122 
      4         GGR9999999
      5         YUU33434324
      6         POL23523552
    ...
```

And now look for example on 2nd row in Snps and base. They have a same numbers (the first 3 chars are not important to me now).

So I created a `commonlist` contained a numbers from `snsp` which also appear in the `base`. The all rows with SAME numbers between dfs. (common has 15k length)

```
common_list = [4112234, 4234122, 23523552]
```

And now I want create three new lists.

`confirmedSnps` = where whole SampleIdInt is identical as in base. In this example: `AFG4234122`. For this I have a sure that `secondName` will be proper.

un_comfirmedSnpS = where I have a good number but first three chars are different. Example: `KWW4112234` in `SnpS` and `ARR4112234` in base. In this case, I'm not sure that `SecondName` is proper, so I need to check it later.

And last `moreThanOne` list. That list should append all duplicate rows. For example If in base I will have KWW4112234 and AFG4112234 both should go to that list.

I wrote a code. It's work fine, but the problem is time. I got 15k elements to filter, and each element processing 4 second. It's mean whole loop will be run for 17h! 
I looking for help in optimization that code.

That's my code:

```
comfirmedSnps = []
un_comfirmedSnps = []
moreThanOne = []
for i in range(len(common)):
    testa = baza[baza['SampleIdInt'].str.contains(common[i])]
    testa = testa.SampleIdInt.unique()
    print("StepOne")
    testb = snps[snps['SampleIdInt'].str.contains(common[i])]
    testb = testb.SampleIdInt.unique()
    print("StepTwo") 
    if len(testa) == 1 and len(testb) == 1:
        if (testa == testb) == True:
            comfirmedSnps.append(testb)
        else:
            un_comfirmedSnps.append(testb)        
    else:
        print("testa has more than one contains records. ")
        moreThanOne.append(testb)
    print("StepTHREE")
    print(i,"/", range(len(common)))
```

I added a Steps prints to check which part takes most of the time. It's the code between `StepOne` and `stepTwo`. First and third steps are running instant.

Can someone help me with that case? For sure most of U will see better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is commonly called [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), which annoyingly enough is called [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in pandas. There's just the minor annoyance of the three initial letters to deal with, but that's easy:

```
snps.numeric_id = snps.SampleIdInt.apply(lambda s: s[3:])
base.numeric_id = base.SampleIdInt.apply(lambda s: s[3:])
```

now you can compute the three dataframes:

```
confirmed = snps.merge(base, on='SampleIdInt')
unconfirmed = snps.merge(
    base, on='numeric_id'
).filter(
    lambda r.SampleIdInt_x != r.SampleIdInt_y
)
more_than_one = snps.group_by('numeric_id').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1)
```

I bet it won't work, but hopefully you get the idea.